# Updating Self-Installed PHP files?

Tags: php, open-source, zip, download, unzip

I am in the final stages of completing my project ([vizulium](http://vizulium.com) - open-source photography CMS). I have one final remaining stumbling block: updating the software.

My idea that I wanting to implement is this:

1. Check newest version at Vizulium website (page just displays current stable version).
2. If newer version exists, and the user requests it:
   a. Zip the updated files on Vizulium server 
   b. Download the files to the user's server
   c. Unzip contents

I already have a tracking system in place that keeps track of the updates (datetime) that I push. I have not began step 2. All is in PHP and mySQL.

Is this a typical implementation of the problem? Do I need to clarify anything?

I am not using FTP since it is a self-install and I assume the user is programming-illiterate.

Comment: Wordpress uses something like this for its sytem - you could dig around the WP source to see how it's accomplished.

Comment: backing up the user's current db data / files before doing anything that potentially overwrites or breaks something would probably also be a good idea

Comment: erk! So you're planning to implement self-modifying code with no privilege separation on a web-based system which relies on file uploads for basic functionality! I hope your security is up to scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is valid, but needs a few extra considerations.

You should connect to your server via HTTPS and with certificate verification to query and fetch any available updates.

You should sign your updates with a private key and have the client verify the updates as authentic before applying them.

If you need to remove an obsolete file from an install, unzipping will not do this, perhaps have an "upgrade.php" script in each upgrade that is executed to perform any extra necessary steps.

Your upgrade script should backup the web directory and database before performing the upgrade, and retain the backup until the user requests to remove it.

Make your upgrades incremental, so to upgraded from 1 -> 3, you need to upgrade to version 2 first. This would be of-course transparent to the user, but would ensure that the upgrades between versions would be complete and all database updates/modifications are applied in the correct order.